# Can I use gpu::Stream for CascadeClassifier_GPU on OpenCV and how?

Tags: opencv, cuda, gpgpu, nvidia, opencv3.0

I use [Opencv 2.4.10](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) (current stable version). And I use `gpu::CascadeClassifier_GPU::detectMultiScale` to detection faces. I want to use it **async** with my CUDA-kernel-code which I launch in separate `cudaStream_t`. But by default `CascadeClassifier_GPU` launch in the default **zero-stream** that make impossible to launch anything async to this on GPU.

As I see here no way to use `gpu::Stream` for `CascadeClassifier_GPU`: [OpenCV DOC link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=detectmultiscale#int%20gpu::CascadeClassifier_GPU::detectMultiScale(const%20GpuMat&%20image,%20GpuMat&%20objectsBuf,%20double%20scaleFactor,%20int%20minNeighbors,%20Size%20minSize))

- Can I use `gpu::Stream` for `CascadeClassifier_GPU` and how?
- If no, then in what version of OpenCV can I do it?

**UPDATE**: So far the only way I've found - use a separate CPU thread to perform the function of the `gpu::CascadeClassifier_GPU::detectMultiScale` and perform it on a separate GPU. But for this at least I need **2** GPUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CascadeClassifier_GPU` uses mixed GPU/CPU implementation and performs extra synchronizations internally, that's why it doesn't support asynchronous mode with `gpu::Stream` parameter. In order to launch it asynchronously with your code, you need to use separate CPU thread for it.

Comment: Ok, I know this, but even if I use separate CPU thread, then my custom CUDA-kernel functions or cudaMemcpy still can't to performe async-simultaneously, because all CUDA-kernal in `CascadeClassifier_GPU` launch in the **default zero-stream** that make **impossible** to execute anything **async-simultaneously** to this on GPU. So far the only way I've found - use a separate CPU thread to perform the function of the `gpu::CascadeClassifier_GPU::detectMultiScale` and perform it on a separate GPU. But for this at least I need 2 GPUs.